# Big O notation for a js Function to check subset

Tags: big-o

i have write a function that to check subset of an array.
For big-o notation, how to explain this function?
is it just O(n) for this function?

```
function isSubset(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.filter(function(e) { return arr1.indexOf(e) < 0 })==0;
}

isSubset(['A','B','C','D','E'],['A','D','Z'])  -> false

isSubset(['A','B','C','D','E'],['A','E','D']) -> true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 rules for 0(n) classification.

**Rule 1:** Always worst Case.

**Rule 2:** Remove Constants.

**Rule 3:** Different inputs should have different variables.

```
  1. (+) for steps in order.

  2. (*) for nested steps.
```

**Rule 4:** Drop Non-dominant terms.

So, the two arrays in your input have different sizes. So, according to rule 3, your time complexity will be `0(n*m)`.

Comment: little confused that is it n^m?  a filter with a indexof .
In this case isSubset(['A','B','C','D','E'],['A','D','Z']) 
filter will loop 5 times,  each time will do a indexOf is it means 3times?

Comment: See, now you've the first array size as 5 and the 2nd array as 3, so it will run for 15 times. But suppose, you've an array of 10000 x 15000 elements. Always think about the performance of your code in worst case, and refactor the code to become a better coder. Look at the performance of code according to the complexities in this link https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/. The performance of your code will be horrible in worst cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it now. one more question, If this function do as refactor way,  how enhance it?

Comment: You can first store the values of subset in one array or list. Then, you can use another loop, to check the value is present or not in the array. Then, the time complexity of the code will be `0(a+b)` which is much better than `0(a*b)`. If you liked my answer, an upvote to my answer is appreciated.

Comment: may i have an example,  not sure how become to a+b

Comment: Look, the sizes of both the input arrays are different. So, according to the rule, for different input sizes, you should take two different variables. So, the time complexity is `0(a+b)`. If it had the same array or same input twice, the time complexity would have been, `0(a+a)`, i.e `0(2a)`. And, we should remove the constants, so the time complexity will be `0(a)`. Don't get confused, between the characters - a, b, n, m are just variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `filter` function will iterate over all the elements so its complexity is `O(n)`. Find the function prototype here [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

While iterating over each element in `filter` you are using `indexOf` function which also iterates over all the elements in the second array till it won't find the matching character so its complexity is also `O(m)`. Find the function prototype here [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

As `indexOf` is nested so its complexity will be multiplied with a `filter` complexity, Which is `O(n*m)`

So the `isSubset` complexity will be `O(n*m)`